# Java EE EAR deployment descriptor eclipse DTD validator

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear

I am trying to fix a small issue regarding the deployment descriptor of a project I am working on. For some reason, Eclipse doesn't validate the XML file against the DTD but i can't figure why.

Here's the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="1.4">
  <display-name>projectName-ear</display-name>
  <module id="WebModule_1266621716287">
    <web>
      <web-uri>projectName-war.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>projectName-war</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

And here's the error I have from eclipse validator :

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'library-directory'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":module, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-role}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<library-directory>` was introduced in Java EE 5. However, you declared the `application.xml` as a J2EE 1.4 application instead of a Java EE 5 application.

```
<application ... version="1.4">
```

So it'll run in J2EE 1.4 backwards compatibility modus and not support the `<library-directory>` at all.

For a Java EE 5 application (GlassFish 2, JBoss AS 4/5, WebSphere 6, etc), use the below as root declaration:

```xml
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
             version="5">
```

Or if you're actually targeting a Java EE 6 container (GlassFish 3, JBoss AS 6/7, WebSphere 7, TomEE 1, etc), then better use the below as root declaration:

```xml
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">
```

Or if you're actually targeting a Java EE 7 container (GlassFish 4, WildFly 8, WebSphere 8, TomEE 2, etc), then better use the below as root declaration (note the new XML namespace domain):

```xml
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
             version="7">
```

Do note that the same applies to other DD XML files such as Servlet's `web.xml`, JSF's `faces-config.xml`, CDI's `beans.xml`, etc. The root XML element declaration and its `version` is very significant!